# CSS adapt the size of a div between two fixed divs

Tags: css

I have 3 divs:

```
<div>
  <div id="div1">Title</div>
  <div id="div2">Some text</div>
  <div id="div3">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Every div have a width: 100%.
The title div height depends on its content so it can evoluate a little bit, and it has a fixed position.
The Footer div has a fixed size (its content cannot change) and a fixed position.

The goal is to have the text div between this two divs, having its size exactly matches the remaining places between title and text div so I can apply a scroll on it.

Can somebody explain to me how to do that ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't the clearest atm. What do you mean by "having its size exactly matches the remaining places between title and text div"?

If you can provide a diagram / drawing, that may help too.

Comment: It means that the title can either take 1 or 2 lines, and the footer height is always 10%.
I need the text div to be between the to divs, and because footer and title are fixed positions I do not want my text div to be behing th footer one

Comment: I think you could use css `grid-auto-rows` property for that: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```css
#div1 {
  background: rgba(0,0,250,0.2)
}

#div2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: rgba(0,250,0,0.2);
  overflow: scroll;
}

#div3 {
  height: 10vh;
  background: rgba(250,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">Title</div>
  <div id="div2">Some text</div>
  <div id="div3">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the clarification in your comment what you're trying to achieve is a basic layout which should be done using the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags rather than reinventing the wheel with divs.

However if you're set on using divs you should use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` on the `#div1` and `#div3` depending on what you need the to do. Using this method you should add apropriate margins to make sure div1 and 3 dont cover div2.